# Identify of Japanese Cherry fruit tree

Tags: identification, fruit-trees, cherries

I bought a cherry fruit tree about a month ago. In my country(Indonesia), that cherry tree called 'ceri jepang' which literally means 'Japanese cherry'. But I searched online and couldn't find the latin name of that species of cherry.

Here is the picture of the tree:

[image]

the unripe fruit:

[image]

Based on [Cherry list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus_subg._Cerasus) in Wikipedia, Japanese cherry are  [Prunus serrulata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus_serrulata), [Prunus jamasakura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus_jamasakura), [Prunus sargentii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus_sargentii), [Prunus Speciosa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus_speciosa), etc but I am sure they are different species because the flower of my tree does not bloom like them. My cherry tree flower only likes very small cherries.

The seller said Japanese Cherry is the sweetest cherry that sold in my country and sweeter than Vietnamese Cherry (that known sweet cherry, but I also don't know the english/latin name).

I found the sweet cherry only found Prunus avium, but I believe that it is a different species because my fruit stem is not as long as Prunus avium.

Anyone knows the latin/english name of my cherry tree? I need it to research about how to take care of that tree.

And also, do cherries always take a long time for the fruit to ripen? I bought it since it has a lot of flowers (small cherries)  but most of them fall off and the rest that survive are still unripe for more than 40 days.