# What is this brown spot in my cherry leaf?

Tags: identification, diseases, leaves, tree-care, fungus

I have a cherry fruit tree that I don't know the species name, but in my country it's called [Japanese Cherry](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/63352/identify-of-japanese-cherry-fruit-tree).

Some of my cherry's leaves have brown spots, it looks like a fungus but also looks like tiny insect eggs. Anyone knows what this is? And should I get rid of all leaves that have that brown spot to prevent spreading?

[image]

[image]

Sorry for bad images, because I don't have a good camera.